Are there any email clients with scheduled delete?
I'm having lots of emails that aren't relevant after a fixed date, for example a promotion voucher that's valid until the next weekend, a receipt that I have to keep for 1 year, or some forms that I have to fill before a deadline in case I want to join something if I have time. Probably somewhat related to this https://support.google.com/mail/thread/102687295/solved-how-to-schedule-the-deletion-of-messages?hl=en
I'd like to set a date for each one of such emails so that on the defined date they'll be deleted if I have no action on them. Are there any such email clients?
